# OpenLayers 4 popup, prevent pointer to target data behind a div

Tags: javascript, openlayers, css

I have a problem with the Popup of OpenLayers 4, when I open the popup info and I'm inside the div with the pointer, it is still triggering the hover popup with the data behind the popup, how can I prevent that?

I'm using this CSS code for the popup:

```
#popup {
  z-index: 20;
  background-color: #fff;
}
```

The popup is created with the overlay layer:

```
overlay = new ol.Overlay({
  element: container,
  autoPan: true,
  autoPanAnimation: {
    duration: 250
  }
});
```

But the pointer still passes through the div. the popup contains a lot of `div` and inside `span`

In the screenshot the hover popup was triggered when the pointer was on the `Vehs` text

[image]

You can refer to this for the code I use for the popup, the only difference is that I have a hover popup, I think the problem is on the creation of the click popup (the one with button) and the real z-index of it.

http://openlayers.org/en/latest/examples/popup.html

Comment: There's no problem if you just followed the OL's example. need more code to figure out any error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the end, I found a very simple way to solve the problem, inside the function I call for the hover popup I add a simple `if` statement

```
map.on('pointermove', function(evt) {

    info.html("");

    if (overlay.getPosition() !== undefined) {
      return;
    }
.....
}
```